# Play Framework 2.1.0 - Using Ebean to query existing database tables

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am having trouble with returning data from a existing database table (SQL Server 2008 R2).  I can successfully authenticate and connect to the database, I have a model created that I attempted to map to a particular table, then as a test tried to return a row count, the row count always returns 0.  I think perhaps I do not understand how Play/Ebean database connectivity works.  At present I have the below:

Model - Data.java:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="someTable")  
public class Data extends Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public int someKey;

    public String someCol;

    public static Finder<Integer,Data> find = new Finder<Integer,Data>( Integer.class, Data.class );

}
```

Controller - Index.java

```
package controllers;

import java.util.*;
import models.Data;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Index extends Controller {

    static int rowCount = Data.find.getMaxRows();

    public static Result index() {
        Result res = ok(rowCount);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Application.conf (Relevant snippets):

```
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server.domain.local/someDB;instance=SQL"
db.default.user=someUser
db.default.password="password"

evolutionplugin=disabled

ebean.default="models.*"
```

I don't profess to understand how Evolutions work, but I do database development work separately in SQL, i.e. DDL and schema creation/modifying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try `findRowCount()` instead of `getMaxRows()`.

Comment: @nkr - findRowCount() worked!  Many thanks for your help, much appreciated, do you know what the intended functionality is of getMaxRows()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you want to do is done by [`findRowCount()`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html#findRowCount%28%29) which returns the number of the rows your query affect. Basically a `COUNT(*)`.

[`getMaxRows()`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html#getMaxRows%28%29) is the equivalent to [`setMaxRows(int)`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html#setMaxRows%28int%29) which is a limitation for the number of rows returned by your query (e.g. `LIMIT` in MySQL).

Comment: Excellent, thanks again nkr, that makes perfect sense now.  getMaxRows() is also the equivalent to T-SQL's SET ROWCOUNT (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)